# Azure Resource Manager SQL db templates

Tags: azure, templates, resources, resource-management, sqldb

I am trying to create an ARM templates for Azure SQL DB deployment. I started by exporting template for an existing Azure sql database which was created and configured from portal. However I see quite a few fields which look a bit unfamiliar to me on usage - examples provided below:

a. kind
b. serviceLevelObjective
c. currentServiceObjectiveId
d. requestedServiceObjectiveId
e. containmentState
f. readScale

Is there any place where I can find information on what each of these properties/keys means and what are the valid values against these so that I know how to use these?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [Azure Rest API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases#Databases_CreateOrUpdate) it has got examples and definitions for parameters.
Also, you don't need all of those, you can just use a "regular" way of creating Azure SQL stuff defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers).

Also, MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163685.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links. Yes agree I can use the simple template. But by looking into the exported template I feel I might lose out on a number of settings if I use the simple template instead. Hence the requirement to understand what the keys mean. For instance I cannot find what the containmentState enumeration values mean. I see mostly 2 being used - does it mean fully/partially/none? Also what could be the meaning of System and System2 for databaseedition? These are just some examples. Without any definitive guidance I find it very difficult to effectively create the template. Any help?

Comment: what the point of using those if you don't understand them? And no, I cannot offer any help beyond this, I've never bothered to figure out what all of those parameters mean. Basic template was always fine for everybody... @shaswatapal

Comment: Well well someone seems pretty annoyed for some reason.  "Basic template was always fine for everybody" => I beg to disagree. You cannot generalize to hide your limitations. But thanks again for attempting to answer. PS: On second thought perhaps I should have been more specific on my earlier statement "Without any definitive guidance I find it very difficult to effectively create the template" => I meant guidance from microsoft, perhaps you felt I meant there was guidance lacking in your response - your response was clear on the limitation that was there in the provided answer

Comment: all the resources are in front of you, if you can't make sense out of those, well. I can't help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, really appreciate. I would like to keep the question open for any other expert as this doesn't unfortunately solve my problem - attribute it to my level of incompetence :(.